# IFFT Synthesis from an empty spectrum

Tags: signal-processing, fft, spectrum, ifft

I'm trying to generate a sawtooth wave using the IFFT.   I can do this successfully by first performing an FFT and then putting that analysed spectrum into the IFFT, however I would really like to be able to write a UI that enables me to draw the bin magnitudes and generate a spectrum from that.   I have been partially successful, however the waveforms don't look quite look/sound right even though the spectrum input is per the formula for synthesising a sawtooth wave.

My question is how do I generate a spectrum array of complex values for an IFFT when all I have are the magnitude values?

I know that bin 0 and 1 are zero valued.   I've been trying to render the wave by only calculating the magnitudes and phases for the significant bins containing the non zero magnitudes.   Am I able to put white noise in the remaining magnitude bins and then calculate the accompanying phases at the centre frequency?     Thanks in advance for your contribution.

Comment: This is more of a DSP theory question than a programming question - it really belongs on http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks Paul.  I'll do that

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how do I generate a spectrum array of complex values for an IFFT when all I have are the magnitude values?

sorry for the clear answer: Not at all. Your values **need** to be complex, so you must offer the user a method to input complex values. Letting the user specify the magnitude is only offering half of the freedom she/he needs to specify arbitrary wave forms.

Comment: I understand the numbers need to be complex.   I'm not trying to IFFT a spectrum of just magnitudes.  I am calculating phases for the magnitudes > 0.   If what you saying is true, how would a synthesiser like the K5000 exist?   It provides a user interface where the user can modify magnitudes without having to edit phases?

Comment: I don't know a device called K5000, but we both agree that magnitude information isn't enough to reproduce a specific waveform using an IFFT. So your approach is lacking half of the information. Maybe that K5000 is not doing an IDFT, but something like an IDCT?

Comment: Thanks for the response Marcus.  If I'm calculating the phases for magnitudes of > 0 based on the note frequency, how might i approach calculating the bins in between these?   are these random numbers?   The appear to be from my FFT analysis efforts.

Comment: I don't know on what basis you are calculating phases, or what your objective is, to be honest. For me, an DFT is a mapping between an N-dimensional vector space over the complex numbers into another N-dimensional vector space over the complex numbers. If you only give real numbers and don't restrict the set of results you want to have, I don't see how there's "right" phases.